# Literature about decidable and undecidable theories

Tags: logic, reference-request, decidability

Is there some modern overview paper about decidable and undecidable theories? Something like Ershov's *Elementary Theories* or Tarski's *Undecidable Theories*. Particularly I am interested in result about undecidability of group theory with modern language and methods.

Comment: Someone has voted to say this question is "too broad". Is there any particular aspect of decidable or undecidable theories you are interested in? For example, what are you interested in beyond the contents of the *Handbook of Mathematical Logic*? You can edit the post to add more details.